# the structure of the input file to ELKI while running LOF

Tags: data-mining, outliers, elki

I want to run the LOF algorithm with ELKI's GUI, but I can't figure out what sort of input file it expects. I have looked over [here](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/InputFormat) and when I try to give it an input csv file with space-separated attribute values for each instance (including the categorical attribute for class, the rest of the attributes are numeric). The file is similar to this (with no header):

```
5   1   1   1   2   1   3   1   1   benign
5   4   4   5   7   10  3   2   1   benign
3   1   1   1   2   2   3   1   1   benign
6   8   8   1   3   4   3   7   1   benign
4   1   1   3   2   1   3   1   1   benign
8   10  10  8   7   10  9   7   1   malignant
1   1   1   1   2   10  3   1   1   benign
2   1   2   1   2   1   3   1   1   benign
2   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   5   benign
4   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   benign
1   1   1   1   1   1   3   1   1   benign
2   1   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   benign
5   3   3   3   2   3   4   4   1   malignant
```

I chose dbc.in as the .csv file, dbc.parser as NumberVectorLabelParser, ClassLabelFilter's index as 9 (since thats the index of the column with the class label) and k = 11

However, it gives me this error:

```
Task failed
de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.exceptions.AbortException: Cannot initialize class labels: 9
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.filter.typeconversions.ClassLabelFilter.filter(ClassLabelFilter.java:106)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.AbstractDatabaseConnection.invokeStreamFilters(AbstractDatabaseConnection.java:114)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.InputStreamDatabaseConnection.loadData(InputStreamDatabaseConnection.java:91)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.database.StaticArrayDatabase.initialize(StaticArrayDatabase.java:119)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.workflow.InputStep.getDatabase(InputStep.java:62)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.KDDTask.run(KDDTask.java:108)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.KDDCLIApplication.run(KDDCLIApplication.java:60)
    at [...]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.data.LabelList.get(LabelList.java:109)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.filter.typeconversions.ClassLabelFilter.filter(ClassLabelFilter.java:102)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.AbstractDatabaseConnection.invokeStreamFilters(AbstractDatabaseConnection.java:114)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.InputStreamDatabaseConnection.loadData(InputStreamDatabaseConnection.java:91)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.database.StaticArrayDatabase.initialize(StaticArrayDatabase.java:119)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.workflow.InputStep.getDatabase(InputStep.java:62)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.KDDTask.run(KDDTask.java:108)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.KDDCLIApplication.run(KDDCLIApplication.java:60)
    at [...]
```

If I don't use the ClassLabel filter, then a popup dialog box appears with this message:

```
SVG Error:

null:-1
The attribute "d" of the element <path> is invalid
```

Could anyone please help me run the algorithm? Would appreciate the help very much, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** missing values in the input data broke the histogram visualizer. This has been fixed, and will work in the next release (missing values will simply be ignored though - there won't be a separate histogram bar to indicate the number of missing values. Contributions are welcome!)

The class label index is relative to the *labels*, not to the CSV file: the filter only sees the labels, nothing else. So you want to use column 0 as class label.

But you shouldn't need to use this filter at all.

The **SVG visualization error** likely arises because of ∞ (infinity, encoded as UTF-8, or maybe NaN too) resulting somewhere. This could be either due to NaN values in the input data<strike>, or because of duplicates in the data</strike>.

In this data set, there are 27 copies of the record

```
1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1
```

The way LOF is defined, if you have k or more duplicates, the LOF score *can* become infinite. At this point, some visualization module fails and sets the some radius or some scale to infinity, and that isn't valid SVG anymore then (I'll open a bug ticket for that)! Welcome to the real world of messy data. ;-)

<strike>Workaround 1: choose k = 30 or larger.</strike>

Workaround 2: don't use the visualization, write the data to a file instead; or **enable only the visualizers you need**, e.g. `-vis.enable scatter|unproj`

<strike>Workaround 3: remove duplicates first.</strike>

Workaround 3: Remove rows with missing values.

None of these changes makes the data set a good choice for outlier detection, however: **the "outliers" in this data set cluster**.

Comment: Thank you so very much! I think missing values were the culprit. I just handled missing values by taking a mean around the column, so it doesn't give that error anymore. However, since the dataset had 34% + records of malignant class instances, it gave me the error of how outliers should be more rare. I have removed the malignant instances to get about 5% of the records as malignant, and its still giving me the same error message, do you have any idea of how much of the total percentage should the outliers be?

Comment: The warning is issued if the least frequent class is exactly 5% or more frequent. Usually, I would aim for at the *very very* most 1%, much better is 0.1%. Outliers are supposed to be rare. In classic 1 dimensional Gaussian models, most people would consider 3 sigma deviations to be "outliers". This corresponds to about 0.27% outliers (or 1 in 370, intuitively one unusual *day* every year). That is the scenario such methods are designed for. It also means the Wisconsin Breast Cancer data set is way too small to talk about "outliers". There should be about ~2 outliers in it.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! No wonder the visualization (not sure if it was related though) I was getting wasn't making that much of a sense, since high LOF values were being calculated even for benign entries. If there were 2 outliers present, would it find it? I guess I should find some other dataset, do you have any recommendations of a dataset I could use to demonstrate the workings of LOF?

Comment: Also, when I try to plot with 2 outliers, a very strange thing happens, the outlier scores for a lot of benign elements appear to be greater (also encircled with a larger circle) than those of the malignant elements, I don't understand why that is. Is it something to do with a small dataset also?

Comment: One more question :) I just applied ELKI on the [wine quality dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine+Quality), and it seems to give interesting results, but I notice that ELKI outputs a matrix of graphs, each with respect two 2 dimensions, is there a way to visualize multi-dimensions in a single graph?

Comment: There are no interesting outlier detection data sets that can be easily visualized in 2. You can use the toy examples to demonstrate the algorithms. The breast cancer data set is a classification data set; there is *no* correspondence like malignant=outliers. For the task of detecting malignant, use a supervised classification technique.

Comment: Btw, I have fixed this issue in the ELKI visualization. It was actually in the histogram classes, that would not tolerate NaN or infinite values well. SVG can be a bit fragile, too. :-(

Comment: Awesome! So it will work on duplicates now? Would I have to download a newer version to test it?

Comment: This is only available in Git right now. It **only affected visualization**, namely of the histograms, which didn't tolerate **missing values**. The bubble visualization was already adapted to tolerate infinite values before, so duplicates should not be an issue.